# Normalizer in $S_5$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I'm considering the normalizer of the subgroup generated by the element $(12)(345)$. I know that this is exactly the elements of $S_5$ that commute with it and it's a subgroup of $S_5$, but not necessarily of the subgroup generated by $(12)(345)$ itself. I certainly have the identity permutation, $(12)(345)$ itself, and its inverse. However, I do not know if there are any others or an efficient algorithm to use. Is there a way to use the conjugacy class of $(12)(345)$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Conjugation of permutations preserves cycle types.

Comment: I know the elements of the conjugacy class of $\langle (12)(345) \rangle$ and that all of them have the same cycle type, a single two-cycle and and a single three-cycle with no elements fixed. I don't know how to relate this to the normalizer, though.

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out how to use the method you described, but I believe the answer is $e$, $(12)$, $(345), $(12)(345)$, and $(12)(435)$. Could you tell me if this is right? If there's a faster algorithm, I would be interested in learning it.

Comment: No, that's not correct. The normaliser of any subgroup is itself a subgroup. Your answer does not include the inverse of $(345)$, @StanMS.

Comment: I'll give an example of my hint, @StanMS. We have for all $\sigma\in N_{S_5}(\langle (12)(345)\rangle)$ and any $\tau\in\langle (12)(345)\rangle$, that $$\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1} =\pi,$$ where $\pi\in \langle (12)(345)\rangle$ has the same cycle type as $\tau$.

Comment: So is the strategy to set $\tau$ equal to each element in $\langle (12)(345) \rangle$? (Just so I can check my answer, does including the inverse of $(345)$ give the right answer?)

Comment: Yes, @StanMS. But you'll have to forgive me: I can't answer your second question just yet, since I'm half asleep; it's nearly 3am here.